# Can't remove backstack using Jetypack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

i'm having really hard time understanding what is going wrong here.

Let's assume i have an app with 2 screens , Home (A) and an adding form (B).
What i'm trying to achieve is having the screen A to be in the backstack, then launching B to do some work , and the going back to A reflecting the changes made in B.

Using compose, navigating from A to B works fine with this command

```
navController.navigate(Screen.AddingForm.route) {
            }
```

But when i try to navigate back (for example pressing the back button , both phisical and a custom one) with this code :

```
    BackHandler(enabled = true) {
        navController.navigate(Screen.Home.route) {
            popUpTo(Screen.AddingForm.route){
                inclusive = true
            }
        }
    }
    if (viewModel.isBackPressed) {
        navController.navigate(Screen.Home.route) {
            popUpTo(Screen.AddingForm.route){
                inclusive = true
            }
        }
    }
```

What happens is that the A screen is shown, but if i press again the back button, the B is shown.
That does not makes any sense to me, is anything wrong with my code?

EDIT:
As suggested, i removed the BackHandler and modified the logic as it follows:

```
if (viewModel.isBackPressed) {
    navController.popBackStack(route = Screen.Home.route, inclusive = false)
}
```

But with the physical back button and the one that triggers the code, the same result happens, the Form (B) is redrawn and the navigation remains where it started

Comment: A call to `navigate` adds a brand new instance to the back stack. Is there a reason you aren't using `popBackStack()`? Is there a reason you are using a `BackHandler` at all, given that the `NavHost` already takes care of handling the system back button for you?

Comment: @ianhanniballake thank you for the response, I tried as you suggested and defined the problems in the Edit

Comment: It sounds like your problem is with your first screen continuing to navigate to your second screen when you return to it. How is your first screen making sure it only navigates exactly once? Please include your first screen's code as it looks like you are mixing up events (which should be processed exactly once) and state (which is read on every recomposition, potentially many, many times).

Comment: @ianhanniballake thank for pointing out the problem, the navigation to B from A was triggered by a boolean condition in A.
Solution was to navigate f A -> B and then reset that condition